# findwindowEX tricky external program

Tags: vb.net, spy++, findwindow, findwindowex

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to get all the way down where it says:

Window 00211286 "" QWidget

[image]

Highlighted in green is what i am trying to find with the code below:

[image]
Currently i have this:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As Integer, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Public Declare Function SendMessageLong& Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long)

Public Const WM_CHAR = &H102
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Public Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = &H203
Public Const ENTER_KEY = 13

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hwndParent As Long = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Genymotion")
    Dim hwndButton As Long = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "")
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "content")
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "mainFrame")
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "")
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "qt_scrollarea_viewport")
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "")
End Sub
```

I get a value for FindWindow and then also for the first findwindowEx.... but after that i get a big fat 0. Then for the last FindWindowEx i get the same number as i did on the first findwindowEx.

Any help would be great!

Comment: While not an answer to the question, note that direct messaging (SendMessage, PostMessage, etc.) to simulate user input is not a reliable in Windows.  Have you looked into using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
    Dim hwndParent As Long = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Genymotion") ' Parent Window by Caption
    Dim hwndButton As Long = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "") ' First Child QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, hwndButton, "QWidget", "") ' Second Child QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "content") ' "content" QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "mainFrame") ' "mainFrame" QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "") ' First Child QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "qt_scrollarea_viewport") ' "qt_scrollarea_viewport" QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndButton, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "") ' First Child QWidget
```

Note what happens in these two lines:

```
    Dim hwndButton As Long = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, "QWidget", "") ' First Child QWidget
    hwndButton = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, hwndButton, "QWidget", "") ' Second Child QWidget
```

The first line gets the first QWidget that has a handle of 001816EC.  In the second line we use the same parent handle, but we pass in the handle of the previously found widget to the second parameter called "hWndChildAfter".  This gets the second QWidget that has a handle of 0011686A.  These two windows are "siblings" to each other.